# Generalization of the sliding ladder problem

Tags: calculus, geometry, algebra-precalculus, iterated-function-system

Suppose we have a ladder of length $1$, and it's sliding down the $y-$axis. We know that the curve enveloped by it is an astroid:

[image]

However, what if we iterate this process? We call this astroid curve $t_1$ and consider an identical ladder sliding down $t_1$ in the same way(with two endpoints on $t_1$ instead of the $x$ and $y$ axis), and call the curve enveloped by that $t_2$. Then we slide a ladder down $t_2$, and so on. I speculate that this will eventually fill up the entire first quadrant.

Is there a way to describe the curve obtained on each iteration?

Comment: So the bottom of the ladder is on the x axis and the top is on $t_1$?

Comment: @martycohen No, both endpoints are on $t_1$

Comment: How do we decide where on $t_1$ the endpoints are? Also, the new lines would all be above $t_1$ (except for the endpoints, which are on $t_1$) so only points above $t_1$ could be on consecutive curves.

Comment: @martycohen So starting off the ladder is on the $y-$axis, with its lower point touching the top of the astroid. Then the ladder slides down the curve $t_1$, until it reaches the end where it lies on the $x-$axis with its left endpoint touching $t_1$. Perhaps a better analogy is to think of it as a skateboard skating down the ramp(which is $t_1$).

Comment: You'll get rather complicated curves, since already $t_2$ has $3$ different segments (one point on the $y$ axis, then both points on $t_1$, then one point on the $x$ axis), and it gets worse from there, since you get a discontinuity every time either of the two endpoints hits a discontinuity.